# ActionController::RoutingError for gem, jQuery, and SCSS assets in Rails 4.1.9 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I have a rails app in production with pretty much everything working great.  I am having two asset pipeline problems.  First, I am using jQuery TE on text areas for rich text editing.  It works fine, but the toolbar image is not rendering in production.  In the production log I get the following:

```
FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-te.png"):
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

In the console for chrome I am getting:
[image: Chrome Console Output]
The asset is being compiled with fingerprint as:

```
jquery-te-d2ff8c0598f255d23777a4e8cfa907d0.png
```

So, it's definitely there, but it seems to call the image without the fingerprint no matter what I do.

The asset is called as a background image in jquery-te-1.4.0.css.scss.  I have tried every pattern I have found for this problem on SO.  Right now, I am trying:

```
.jqte_tool_icon {
  display:block;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
  background: image-url("jquery-te.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have also tried using `background-image`, `asset-path`, and just about every way I can think of, but no luck.

My second problem might be related.  When using the gem 'font-awesome-rails' it works fine locally, but in production I get boxes where the icons should be.  The production log shows:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):
```

When looking in the public/assets folder, this font exists, but with the addition of the fingerprint.  I looked at the bottom of the gem README on github and followed the suggestion about apache requiring a relative route:

```
 config.action_controller.relative_url_root  = "/myrailsapp"
```

Making this change did not help.  Like the jquery-te it is calling the asset without the fingerprint and thus not finding it.

Additional Info:
Rails - 4.1.9
Ruby - 2.1.2
jQuery-te - 1.4.0
font-awesome-rails 4.3.0.0

Running on an AWS server with CentOS 6.5 using apache and passenger.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you do `<img src="/assets/jquery-te.png" />` or `<%= image_tag "jquery-te.png" %>` in your code?

Comment: Neither.  The image is called in the as background image in the scss.